# Jquery UI - dynamically bind the keypress event on the clicked div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, keyboard-events, jquery-resizable

[jsFiddle demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/e2yfC/24/)

Hi Guys,
I want to bind the keypress event handler when i click the div layer as given in the above demo. The feature is to use the delete key to remove the selected layer.

But when i hit the delete key, the keypress handler doesn't fire. Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove '`()`':

```
$this.on("keypress", keyAction);
```

You are adding `undefined` as handler: `$this.on("keypress", keyAction())` is equal to `$this.on("keypress", undefined)` in your case, as `keyAction` function does not return anything.

Also your `div` must be focusable, in order to receive keyboard events. For that reason you need to add `tabindex` on it:

```
<div class="dragClass" tabindex="0">
```

Then in `selectAction` focus your div to receive keypress event:

```
$this.focus();
```

This is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/A7YbJ/)

For more information about adding `keyboard event`s on static elements such as `div`, look at [here](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/WD-WCAG20-TECHS/SCR29.html):

Answer (score 2):

```
Use this code it execute for delete key        
             $("#ParentDIV").keyDown(function (e) {
              if (e.keyCode == 46) {
               // Do it
              }
             });
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for an element to receive keypress events, it needs focus.  One way is to add a tabindex.  If you click on your element then click a keyboard button in the below fiddle, you'll get your event.  I stripped down the fiddle a bit and removed the draggable which is interfering with focus.

http://jsfiddle.net/e2yfC/27/

Comment: but i need draggable feature also.